# Are there known undecidable statements which are Gödel sentences, but were not always known to be such?

Tags: math-history, incompleteness, decidability

As I understand it, Gödel and Rosser proved constructively that for any consistent, effectively generated system within which basic arithmetic can be carried out, an infinite amount of statements which can be proven neither true nor false within the system can be generated. The proof involves encoding the systems own axioms ad rules of deduction using properties of numbers. The resulting statement has the form $\neg \exists n:F(n)$ for some primitive recursive F. The crux of the proof is that this statement can be interpreted to state its own undecidability. Such a statement is commonly called a Gödel sentence.

My question is if there are any statements in some formal system which are Gödel sentences which mathematicians were interested in before it was known the statement was a Gödel sentence.

Comment: Godel sentences are of no interest in any field of mathematics other than for their use in showing systems are incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Statements that are undecidable in Peano arithmetic, but can be stated in it and are provable in something larger such as ZF or second-order arithmetic, include [$\varepsilon_0$ induction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5065/what-is-induction-up-to-epsilon-0), [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) and the [Paris–Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem). I'm not sure, though, if they can be formatted as Gödel sentences. See also @DanielWainfleet's comment.

Comment: There was the Q of whether there is a finitistic algorithm that can take, as input, any polynomial P in 2 or more variables, and integer co-efficients, and determine whether the equation P=0 had a solution in which all the variables took values in $\Bbb N.$ After many years and much work it was shown that if such an algorithm existed then there would be an algorithm in PA for deciding which sentences are theorems of PA.